# WatiN Multiple file upload

Tags: watin

I'm trying out WatiN for some specification tests. I hit a snag though when i was trying to figure out how to setup a file upload with multiple files (my test with just one file worked fine). Is it possible to setup multiple files in an upload-input using WatiN?

Comment: How is the upload handled? How do you "setup" multiple files? Won't a simple for through all the files do it?

Comment: Well the markup i picked is an input with the multiple attribute set. Im just not quite sure how to test that.